# Jmeter: Getting this error : XML Parsing Error:

Tags: jmeter

XML Parsing Error:

> syntax error Location: https://app.scheduleonce.com/SignUp.aspx?e=28 Line Number 3, Column 1:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Answer (score 0):

it looks like two different problems, in my opinion.
It seems that your problem lies primarily in the failure of SSL-handshake.

The XML error then results from the response that is not compliant to xml.

My first thought was, maybe you used the wrong port for ssl-requests?